# Can't create client for SOAP 1.1 using axis 1 or axis 2

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

I have tried to create client with axis both versions , I even tried ws-import but noting is working .

U can find WSDL here

Problem with axis 2

```
  <wsdl:message name="getReservationbyPNRRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="OTA_ReadRQ" element="tns:OTA_ReadRQ"/>
    <wsdl:part name="AAReadRQExt" element="ns1:AAReadRQExt"/>
  </wsdl:message>
```

It complains that this message have two parts, I tried to set the style to be rpc.

```
org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder$WSDLProcessingException: The binding operation getAvailability is RPC/literal. The message parts for this operation must use the type attribute as specificed by WS-I Basic Profile specification (4.4.1).  Message part, OTA_AirAvailRQ, violatesthis rule.  Please remove the element attribute and use the type attribute.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.addPartToElement(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2066)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.getNewComplextType(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1931)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.createSchemaForPorttype(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1601)
```

And when I use axis 1 it complains about that

```
2003\_05\MoneyOrPercentageType.java:28: MoneyOrPercentageType(java.math.BigDecimal) is already defined in org.opentravel.www.OTA._2003._05.MoneyOrPercentageType
    public MoneyOrPercentageType(java.math.BigDecimal _value) {
```

Can any body advice me how to create client from this wsdl ???

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem , I used CXF to solve this problem,
I edit the wsdl to be rpc , by changing the binding style to be rpc instead of document.

Thanks